# Is there a book about SYMAP?

Tags: history, symap

I'm aware of several books on the history and developement of GIS, but not one specifically about SYMAP.

SYMAP was developed in 1963 and is considered the first automated computer mapping program.

Has there been a book written specfically about the development of SYMAP, it's impact and influence?

Comment: Full Text is available online http://www16.us.archive.org/stream/symappotentialmu00mays/symappotentialmu00mays_djvu.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go for a couple of pages
.
http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic39008.files/History_LCG.pdf

I do still remember the maps all made out of printing lots of alphanumeric characters on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

The link above is broken posted above but Nick's book covers this period at the Harvard with plenty of SYMAP details.

Charting the Unknown: How Computer Mapping at Harvard Became GIS

> Charting the Unknown takes readers back more than four decades to the Harvard Laboratory for Computer Graphics and Spatial Analysis where a variety if professionals converged to rethink thematic mapping, spatial analysis, and what we now call GIS. The book includes a CD that contains interviews with important figures at the Harvard Laboratory, three movies showing animated, visualization, and scanned copies of Context publications (from 1968 to 1983) describing research-related activities at the Lab.

ISBN-10: 1589481186

ISBN-13: 978-1589481183

Answer (score 1):

I used Symap since 1970 with Sylvie Rimbert and I wrote an adaptation (in French) of SYMAP in 1976; the software was used in our laboratory (Regional Geography, became Image,ville, environnement - Strasbourg) and subsequently by other universities in France in which I made presentations. The students in Strasbourg practiced it until around 1994. Subsequently, we still used the calculations for trend surfaces in the 2000s, but not for plots! Excellent software for learning, even though many things have changed!

Colette Cauvin, Honorary Professor at the University of STRASBOURG

*Website*: [www.geocarto.eu](http://www.geocarto.eu)

*Mail*: [miradou@geocarto.eu](http://mailto:miradou@geocarto.eu)

*Citation*: CAUVIN C., 1976, Manuel d'utilisation du programme SYMAP pour sortie automatique de cartes thématiques. Adaptation française du SYMAP Opérator's Manual. Laboratoire de Cartographie Thématique. Strasbourg. Cahier n° 1. 121 p.